# NodeJS TwitchAPI online/offline status

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, twitch

I am trying to check Streams are Online or Offline...

But I have 1 problem this request is not required for all users.. only 1 or max 2 when 1 is from it online and 1 is offline...

Here is  an example:
In the MySQL are 3 Streams
test1
test2
test3
test4
(1, 2, 3 and 4 are the streams...)
(when ALL offline my output is this...)
test4 is offline and this 4times.

Script:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var parser = require('json-parser');
var JSON = require('JSON');
var mysql  = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'status',
  password : '',
  database : 'all_channels'
});

connection.query("SELECT * FROM channels", function(error, rows, response, fields) {
    if (!!error) {
        console.log('Error in Query!');
    } else {
        for(var i in rows) {


console.log(rows[i])
                request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+rows[i].channels+'?client_id=(I have removed the ID from intent)', function (error, response, html) {
        var profileyt = JSON.parse(html);


if (profileyt["stream"] !== null) {
                        console.log(profileyt["stream"]["channel"]["status"]);
                    } else {


request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'+rows[i].channels+'?client_id=(I have removed the ID from intent)', ', function (error, response, html) {
                            var profiletest = JSON.parse(html);


console.log(''+profiletest["display_name"]+' is offline');
})
}})}}});
```

Console Output:
C:\Bot>node test2.js

```
RowDataPacket { channels: 'test1', status: 'offline' }
RowDataPacket { channels: 'test2', status: 'offline' }
RowDataPacket { channels: 'test3', status: 'offline' }
RowDataPacket { channels: 'test4', status: 'offline' }

Test4 ist offline
Test4 ist offline
Test4 ist offline
Test4 ist offline
```

I have spent 2-3 days trying to fix it but I still have no idea...

Comment: of course it's because you are executing an asynchronous function inside a for loop

Answer (score 0):

The result is

```
Test4 ist offline
Test4 ist offline
Test4 ist offline
Test4 ist offline
```

because you are calling `rows[i].channels` inside in an asynchronous function which is 
the asynchronous function is also inside a loop

See this

The loop is already ended or the `i` becomes the row before the callback of request2 has been called which is why it is always displayed only your last channel

```
for (var i in rows) {
        request1('blahblah...', function(error, response, html) {
            // rows[i].channels this will always displayed your last row data
            request2(rows[i].channels, function (error, response, html) {
            })
        })
    }
}
```

To solve that create a seperate function

```
function getChannelStatus(row) {
    // now the row will be pass is the correct one istead of the last row like your previous code
    request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + row.channels + '?client_id=(I have removed the ID from intent)', function(error, response, html) {
            var profileyt = JSON.parse(html);


            if (profileyt["stream"] !== null) {
                console.log(profileyt["stream"]["channel"]["status"]);
            } else {


                request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + row.channels + '?client_id=(I have removed the ID from intent)', function (error, response, html) {
                    var profiletest = JSON.parse(html);


                    console.log('' + profiletest["display_name"] + ' is offline');
                })
        }
    })
}

connection.query("SELECT * FROM channels", function(error, rows, response, fields) {
    if (!!error) {
        console.log('Error in Query!');
    } else {
        for (var i in rows) {

            console.log(rows[i])
            getChannelStatus(rows[i]);
        }
    }
});
```